# In PHP, strpos() fails to find double quote ('"') in string

Tags: php, strpos

Both this:

```
echo 'Tok: '.$tok.' Strpos: '.strpos($tok, "\"").' length: '.strlen($tok).'<br>';
```

And this:

```
echo 'Tok: '.$tok.' Strpos: '.strpos($tok, '"').' length: '.strlen($tok).'<br>';
```

Result in the following output:

```
Tok: "fresh Strpos: length: 11
```

Strpos is failing completely to find the double quote, it returns false (I checked with strpos() === false).  Can someone tell me what's going on here?  I can find no documentation suggesting that strpos can't handle double quotes, why isn't it finding it?  I am at my wits end.

Comment: Its working for me in 5.3.0...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you 1000% sure that the double quote in `$tok` is actually a literal `"` and not a HTML entity? Can you check your HTML code?

Comment: This. Check the source of the webpage when you echo $tok.

Comment: Was just coming back to post that I'd discovered that.  It's an HTML entity alright: &quot;  *head desk* Input sanitization for the fail.

Comment: Input “sanitisation” totally for the fail at all times! HTML-encoding must not happen until the moment you put the text into HTML output; doing it at the input stage is doomed to failure, messed up database contents and security holes where other content comes in.

Answer (score 3):

Using php at the command line, your code works for me.

I noticed you didn't specify the content of $tok. I also noticed it lookes like you're outputting to a browser. Are you sure that the html

```
&quot
```

isn't being used instead of the actual quote character?

Answer (score 1):

strpos($tok, '"') is equaling === 0 in your case since the very first element in $tok is a double-quote ("). Then when you print out 0 you get nothing because it is a boolean FALSE.

> This function may return Boolean
> FALSE, but may also return a
> non-Boolean value which evaluates to
> FALSE, such as 0 or "". Please read
> the section on Booleans for more
> information. Use the === operator for
> testing the return value of this
> function - https://www.php.net/strpos

Comment: Nah, only when it's FALSE the output will be empty; otherwise it should be a numeric `0` shouldn't it`?